# Example of a random variable s.t. first $2n$ moments exist and rest of the moments don’t exist

Tags: probability

We have to construct a random variable $X$ such that its first $2n$ moments exist and rest of the moments don’t exist.

I cannot think of an example which satisfy this can, anybody help me to solve this? I tried various examples. Please help if anybody have knowledge about it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, show us what you tried so far as well.

Answer (score 1):

The CDF $1-x^{-k}$ on $[1,\,\infty)$ is an example of a [Pareto dstribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution), with PDF $kx^{-k-1}$ on its support, so $\Bbb EX^n<\infty$ iff $0\le n<k$. For your purposes, $k=2n+1$ works. Or it *would*, if you'd said you want higher moments to be infinite. Since you want them to be nonexistent, make the distribution even so its PDF is $\tfrac12k|x|^{-k-1}$ on the support $\Bbb R\setminus(-1,\,1)$. If you'd prefer all of $\Bbb R$ as a support, with whatever smoothness conditions you might seek, I leave it to you to tweak this.